# Measure of subsets of profinite groups

Tags: gr.group-theory, profinite-groups, haar-measure

Let $G$ be an infinite profinite group, so $$G=\lim_{\longleftarrow}G/N$$ where $N$ runs through the open normal subgroups. I have two questions:

1. Is $G$ of Haar measure zero in the compact group $\prod_NG/N$?
2. What is the relation between the Haar measure of a subset $E$ of $G$ and the numbers $\frac{|EN/N|}{|G/N}$, the size of the image of $E$ in $G/N$?

Comment: You probably want $G$ connected? Otherwise, just take a finite simple group.

Comment: @abx Profinite group is just a totally disconnected compact group. Sure I mean an infinite profinite group as I would edit.

Comment: Yes, I think that 1 has a positive answer (it's a good exercise).

Comment: For 2, there's an obvious inequality (for $E$ measurable, $\lambda(E)\le\inf_N|EN/N|/|G/N|$) which for $E$ dense of measure zero is clearly not an equality.

Comment: @YCor I choose this title because of my first question.

Comment: @YCor about your obvious inequality, I should say that I really want an inequality in the inverse direction. Does there exist anyone??

Comment: @YCor I do not insist on this title, and I'll change it if I get a better offer.

Comment: Suggestion of title: "measure of subsets of profinite groups". About "*I really want an inequality in the inverse direction*", see the second half of my second comment.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1) The measure of a closed subgroup $H$ of a profinite group $G$ is $\frac{1}{\vert G:H \vert}$. So $G$ has measure zero in $\prod G/N$ if and only if it has infinite index. This way you should be able to show that $G$ always has measure zero in $\prod G/N$.

2) As Yves mentioned, you always have the inequality $\mu(S) \le \inf \frac{\vert NS/N\vert}{\vert G/N \vert}$ for any measurable subset $S$. In fact the right-hand side is the measure of the closure of $S$. If $S$ is closed it is an equality. If $G$ is the profinite completion of an abstract countable group $\Gamma$, then $\mu(\Gamma)=0$, but the closure of $\Gamma$ is $G$.